# mysql SELECT * WHERE date + 7 days >= $today

Tags: mysql, date

I just want to know if there is a way to do this process doing just one call to the database.
I basically need to count entries from a database where today's date is older than the field 'date_out' + 7 days. I was thinking in something like:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d"); //this is the format of date_out in my db!

$count_query = "SELECT count(*) FROM `group` WHERE ADDDATE('date_out', INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= $today  ";
$count_result = mysql_query($count_query) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$query_data = mysql_fetch_row($count_result);
$number_ty = $query_data[0];

if ($number_ty >= 1) {
// do something
}
```

$number_ty is always 0 with this code.
The goal of this question, as stated before, is to know if the count can be done in just one mysql call instead of two. I'm aiming to just simplicity, cleanliness and laziness :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be quoting `date_out`:

```
ADDDATE(date_out, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

You *should* be quoting `$today`:

```
<= '$today'
```

Here is a corrected query. Nevertheless, I would advise that you look into Mysqli or PDO. The library you're using is deprecated.

```
$count_query = "SELECT count(*) FROM `group` WHERE ADDDATE(date_out, INTERVAL 7 DAYS) <= '$today'";
```

Comment: Just one word: AMAZING!!You're just that, Asad. Fast and right on the coin! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Comment: @cbarg You're welcome, but please don't just ignore the warning about Mysql. You're missing out on all sorts of fun stuff.

Comment: I'm looking into it to start shifting to mysqli. I really didn't know it was announced to be deprecated. Thanks

Comment: Asad. I'm trying to get into mysqli but I need some guidance. Here a simple question, in an example with mysql I have $result = mysql_query($count_query); when in mysqli it would be something like $result = mysqli_query($link, $count_query); Is there any way to avoid the $link every single time I want to do a query?

Comment: @cbarg Glad to see you're taking the time to get into it. No, but I don't think it is that inconvenient. You might like the `$link->query("SELECT * FROM ETC")` syntax better.

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered correctly, you need to use the right type of quotes.  Single-quotes are for string literals and date literals.  MySQL uses back-ticks for column-name delimiters.

Also I would leave the `date_out` column alone, and apply the calculation to the fixed date $today.  It will make it easier for MySQL to use an index on `date_out`.

Also MySQL has a builtin function [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) so you can avoid inserting a PHP variable and therefore it's easier to protect against SQL injection.

```
. . .
$count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `group` 
    WHERE `date_out` <= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)";
. . .
```

Comment: As I said to Vyctor, I need the column date_out+7 days instead of $today+7 days. Asad was right in his answer. Now I need to start moving to mysqli :-/ THANK YOU, Mr Bill!!!

Comment: @cbarg, notice I've changed the expression above to use SUBDATE() instead of ADDDATE().

Answer (score 1):

`'date_out'` means string with value `"date_out"` which is not valid date

`` `date_out` ``  is a column name and you want to use this one

You've mixed `'` with `` ` `` (quote with backtick). <del>In postgres `'` has a different meaning (column name) but</del> in [MySQL it's string escape character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html).

And you also may use construction:

```php
$today = date("Y-m-d", time() - 7*24*3600); // 7 days
```

Or in SQL:

```
WHERE date_out <= ADDDATE( NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAYS)"
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, Vyktor, but what I need is to have the comlumn date_out+7 days instead of $today+7 days. Asad (see the other answer) was right on. THANKS!!!

Comment: PostgreSQL uses `"` for column/table identifier, and `'` for string literals and date literals, like other SQL databases.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html